# Plotting data from a csv file on a R map, highlighting their different origin

Tags: r, plot, maps, rworldmap

I am new using R and I'm finding very difficult plotting these data
I already obtained my map (using rworldmap). Here the 2 lines of code that I used:

```
library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
plot(newmap)
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-180, 180), ylim = c(-90, 90), asp = 1, fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="lightblue",)
```

Then I did as follows in order to show the content of my .csv file

```
coordinates <- read.csv("seqmap.csv", header=T, fill=T, col.names=c("ID CODE", "latitude", "longitude", "sample nature", "seq.methods"), row.names=NULL)
head(coordinates)
```

**Now here is the problem:**
I want as polygon:

SQUARE for sample nature=sediment

CIRCLE for sample nature=water

And as filling color for the chosen polygon

1) RED for seq.methods = Illumina

2) BLUE for seq.methods = 454

3) GREEN for seq.methods = Ion torrent

4) YELLOW for seq.methods = Sanger

As examples:
For a sample of sediment sequenced with Illumina: a square with red as a filling color

For a sample of water sequenced with 454: a circle with blue as a filling color

I am stucked at this point and with my knowledge I feel as I can't go any further :(
At the following link you can find the .csv file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t812lf6xgc0d6kf/seqmap.csv?dl=0

Thank you in advance for any help and sorry for any grammar/spelling mistake, English is not my first language :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with characters instead of polygons, you may want to try it like this:

```
library(rworldmap)
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "low")
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/t812lf6xgc0d6kf/seqmap.csv?dl=1", csv <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
coordinates <- read.csv(csv, header=T, fill=T, sep=";", col.names=c("ID CODE", "latitude", "longitude", "sample nature", "seq.methods"), row.names=NULL)

pdf(pdffile <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf"), width = 80, height = 40)
plot(newmap, xlim = c(-180, 180), ylim = c(-90, 90), asp = 1, fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="lightblue",)

with(coordinates, 
     points(x=longitude, y=latitude, cex=.5, # reduce symbol size a bit
            col=adjustcolor(c("Illumina"="red", "454"="blue", "ion torrent"="green", "Sanger"="yellow")[as.character(seq.methods)], alpha.f = .5), 
            pch=c("sediment"=15, "water"=19)[as.character(sample.nature)]
     )
)
dev.off()
shell.exec(pdffile) # open pdf doc on windows to zoom/pan easily...
```

Comment: Hi lukeA, thank you for the help! I can't fully understand the second part,
    with(coordinates, 
     points(x=longitude, y=latitude, cex=.5, # reduce symbol size a bit
            col=adjustcolor(c("Illumina"="red", "454"="blue", "ion torrent"="green", "Sanger"="yellow")[as.character(seq.methods)], alpha.f = .5), 
            pch=c("sediment"=15, "water"=19)[as.character(sample.nature)]
     )
)
dev.off()
shell.exec(pdffile) # open pdf doc on windows to zoom/pan easily...
It just shows me the world map in pdf format (<- good idea!), but the points aren't plotted... Where I get wrong?

Comment: The points should be there, but very tiny. Maybe put `cex` back to `cex=1` (or larger) and/or reduce the document dimensions in `width` and `height`, to squeeze it more together? Or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Nope, I reran it and it works here. As I said, you may need to play with `width`, `height`, `cex` and also `alpha.f`, which controls the transparency of the points (1 = solid, 0 = transparent). In addition, it looks better with `resolution="high"`. :)

Comment: There was just a little problem in the reading of the .csv, solved :) I played a little bit with the parameters and it worked beautifully! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

As your data points are spread all over the world, it can be hard to distinguish the points on the map when you plot everything in one map. As an alternative you can create a faceted plot with a close-up for several parts of the world. I propose the following steps:

**1:** Read the data and make sure they have the right class:

```
coordinates <- read.csv2("seqmap.csv", header=T, fill=T,
                         col.names=c("ID.CODE", "latitude", "longitude", "sample.nature", "seq.methods"),
                         row.names=NULL)
coordinates$latitude <- as.numeric(as.character(coordinates$latitude))
coordinates$longitude <- as.numeric(as.character(coordinates$longitude))
```

**2:** Load the needed libraries:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
```

**3:** Create clusters of points and assign cluster-values to the points:

```
km <- kmeans(coordinates[,c("longitude","latitude")], centers = 6)
coordinates$cluster <- km$cluster
```

**4:** Get the maps for the different clusters:

```
> km$centers
  longitude  latitude
1 -156.7000  71.37000
2  -88.3875  28.82875
3  -39.0700 -17.65200
4  139.3400  35.88667
5   94.4150 -67.29500
6  -64.5000  32.17000

map1 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -156.7, lat = 71.37), zoom = 7)
map2 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -88.3875, lat = 28.82875), zoom = 9)
map3 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -39.07, lat = -17.652), zoom = 9)
map4 <- get_map(location = c(lon = 139.34, lat = 35.88667), zoom = 8)
map5 <- get_map(location = c(lon = 94.415, lat = -67.295), zoom = 4)
map6 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -64.5, lat = 32.17), zoom = 10)
```

**5:** Create the maps and store them as objects:

```
p1 <- ggmap(map1) +
  geom_point(data=coordinates[coordinates$cluster==1,], aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("sediment"=21,"water"=22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Illumina"="red")) +
  guides(shape=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Alaska")

p2 <- ggmap(map2) +
  geom_point(data=coordinates[coordinates$cluster==2,], aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("sediment"=21,"water"=22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Illumina"="red","ion torrent"="green")) +
  guides(shape=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("New Orleans")

p3 <- ggmap(map3) +
  geom_point(data=coordinates[coordinates$cluster==3,], aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("water"=22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("454"="blue")) +
  guides(shape=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Brazil")

p4 <- ggmap(map4) +
  geom_point(data=coordinates[coordinates$cluster==4,], aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("sediment"=21)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("454"="blue")) +
  guides(shape=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Japan")

p5 <- ggmap(map5) +
  geom_point(data=coordinates[coordinates$cluster==5,], aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("water"=22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("Sanger"="yellow")) +
  guides(shape=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Antartica")

p6 <- ggmap(map6) +
  geom_point(data=coordinates[coordinates$cluster==6,], aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods), size=3) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c("water"=22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("454"="blue","Illumina"="red")) +
  guides(shape=FALSE, fill=FALSE) +
  ggtitle("Bermuda")
```

**6:** Create a separate legend:

```
p0 <- ggplot(data=coordinates, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, shape=sample.nature, fill=seq.methods, color=seq.methods)) +
  geom_point(size=4) +
  scale_shape_manual("Sample:",values=c("sediment"=21,"water"=22)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Method:",values=c("454"="blue","Illumina"="red","ion torrent"="green","Sanger"="yellow")) +
  scale_color_manual("Method:",values=c("454"="blue","Illumina"="red","ion torrent"="green","Sanger"="yellow")) +
  theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill=NA))

# function to extract the legend (borrowed from: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs )
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

legend <- g_legend(p0)
lwidth <- sum(legend$width)
```

**7:** Create the final plot with:

```
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, ncol=2),
             legend, widths=unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - lwidth, lwidth), nrow=1)
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jaap, this clustered version worked great for this situation!
I was impressed by how fast and detailed was your answer, if it's not a problem I want to ask you how to generalize this example, in other words: if I have a very extended dataset in .csv form (in the order of 600-800 locations) how can I make the world map (non-clustered)? Using also the indications given by @lukeA, I was able to get the world map in pdf, but there is something wrong in the plotting phase... The points aren't shown on the map and I'm not able to add the legend :( Can you just indicate me the steps?

Comment: Problem solved, there were just a couple of problems in my complete script. I am still new at using R, but working hard to improve :) Thank you again